# Remove first and last instance of a string?

Tags: php, string

How can I remove the **first** instance of a certain piece of html from a string.

I'm looking to remove

```
      </tr>
    </table></td>

  </tr
```

which is near the begining, but it also appears throughout the string.

I also need a way to do the same thing but the **last** instance of it.

Anyone know?

Comment: Are you dynamically building this string?  Perhaps there's another option as opposed to the dreaded preg_replace...

Comment: What you really need to do is find what is creating that erroneous output and fix it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you know roughly how close to the end of the string the substring that you want to replace is, you use `substr_replace()` with a negative `$start` and `$length` parameters, or you could just code up a function by hand to actually go through, find the last occurrence, then delete it. something like this (untested, written very quickly):

```
function replace_last_occurrence($haystack, $needle) {
    $pos = 0;
    $last = 0;

    while($pos !== false) {
        $pos = strpos($haystack, $needle, $pos);
        $last = $pos;
    }

    substr_replace($haystack, "", $last, strlen($needle));
}
```

similar, for first occurrence

```
function replace_first_occurrence($haystack, $needle) {        
    substr_replace($haystack, "", strpos($haystack, $needle, $pos), 
        strlen($needle));
}
```

you could also generalize this to replace the nth occurrence:

```
function replace_nth_occurrence($haystack, $needle, $n) {
    $pos = 0;
    $last = 0;

    for($i = 0 ; $i <= $n ; $i++) {
        $pos = strpos($haystack, $needle, $pos);
        $last = $pos;
    }

    substr_replace($haystack, "", $last, strlen($needle));
}
```

Comment: If you don't care about cases sensitivity you may use strripos() to find last occurrence of string in string. http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php

Answer (score 1):

simplest way is to explode/split the string shift the top and pop the last then implode what's left with you're separator and concatenate the three.. i.e.:

```
$separator = 'your specified html separator here';
$bits = explode($separator , $yourhtml );
$start = array_shift($bits);
$end = array_pop($bits);
$sorted = $start . implode($separator,$bits) . $end;
```

(not tested)

Comment: actually, the `$count` parameter for `str_replace()` is passed by reference and is used to store the number of replacements that the function makes. it doesn't allow you to set a limit.

Comment: Maybe you should add some safeguard to your code for the case where string to be deleted is not present.

Comment: f! you're right must be thinking of something else - ty for the catch (edited)

Answer (score 1):

This will delete last occurrence:

```
$needle = <<<EON
    </tr>
  </table></td>

</tr
EON;

if(preg_match('`.*('.preg_quote($needle).')`s', $haystack, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
  $haystack = substr_replace($haystack, '', $m[1][1], strlen($m[1][0]));
}
```

As additional bonus you may ignore varying number of whitespaces within searched fragment like this:

```
if(preg_match('`.*('.implode('\s+', array_map('preg_quote', preg_split('`\s+`', $needle))).')`s', $haystack, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
  $haystack = substr_replace($haystack, '', $m[1][1], strlen($m[1][0]));
}
```

Or even search case-insensitively by adding i-flag to regexp:

```
if(preg_match('`.*('.implode('\s+', array_map('preg_quote', preg_split('`\s+`', $needle))).')`is', $haystack, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
  $haystack = substr_replace($haystack, '', $m[1][1], strlen($m[1][0]));
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You'll be wanting [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). Replace that section with empty space (eg:"")

Comment: -1 Won't work. From the docs: Replace **all** occurrences of the search string with the replacement string.