# Delete first instance of string with PHP

Tags: php

How do I delete the first instance of a substring in another string with PHP? Thanks.

Comment: This is a duplicate, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145290/remove-first-and-last-instance-of-a-string A solution is provided there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this may do the trick.

```
function replaceFirst($input, $search, $replacement){
    $pos = stripos($input, $search);
    if($pos === false){
        return $input;
    }
    else{
        $result = substr_replace($input, $replacement, $pos, strlen($search));
        return $result;
    }
}

$input = "This is a test. This is only a test.";
$search = "test";
echo replaceFirst($input, $search, "replaced!");
// "This is a replaced!. This is only a test."
```

Sorry for all the edits, had some weird formatting issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try something with the general idea of this:

```
$search = "boo";
$str = "testtestbootest";
$pos = strpos(strrev($str), strrev($search));
$newstr = substr($str, 0, $pos) . substr($str, $pos + strlen($search));
```

Answer (score 0):

if your regex skills are up to it
use preg_replace, with a limit = 1

```
mixed preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php