# Remove the first paragraph tags from string

Tags: php, html, string

String

```
"<p>This is </p><p>Stackoverflow</p><p>site for programmers</p>"
```

Required Output

```
"This is <p>Stackoverflow</p><p>site for programmers</p>"
```

Small function

```
function remove_p($string)
{
$first_p=substr($string,0,3);
$p="<p>";
if($first_p==$p)
{
$string=str_replace('<p>','',$string,$temp=1);
$string=str_replace('</p>','',$string,$temp=1);

}
return $string;
}
```

But it removes all the `<p> </p>` tags.Why so?
I am basically writing this to remove the first paragraph tags created by ckeditor.

Comment: It does? -- http://codepad.org/YlJ291bO

Comment: Is it a static line or it can be any line you want to remove 1st paragraph tag?

Comment: The ckeditor adds <p> tags to the **starting** string, which I want to remove. So i am writing this small function to see if the first three letters are para tags and if yes then remove them. But all the tags are removed.That is the problem.

Comment: @AmalMurali Yes but it removes all the <p> </p> tags.

Answer (score 3):

`str_replace` acts on all occurrences of a substring, not just the first. You will want to use a different function.

```
$string = preg_replace('~<p>(.*?)</p>~is', '$1', $string, /* limit */ 1);
```

To only remove the first `<p>` and `</p>` if at the start of the string, add a `^` after the first `/`.

See also: [Using str_replace so that it only acts on the first match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/php-str-replace-that-only-acts-on-the-first-match)

Comment: Count: If passed, this will be set to the number of replacements performed.  Then in php site they said no of times is controlled by fourth param

Comment: @HS: the fourth argument *is* 1. `/* limit */` is just an explanatory comment.

Comment: No,no  I was talking about str_replace. In php site they say the fourth param is count. It will control how many instanes will be edited. http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: @HS: That is not the parameter's purpose. It is so you can save a call to substr_count when you need to replace all occurrences of the substring anyway, as in `$s = str_replace($a, $b, $s, $c); echo "Replaced $a with $b $c times.";`

Comment: Oh sorry! I mixed up the 'count' and 'limit' . When I echoed the temp variable, it showed 2. It is just an  indication of how many edited, not controlling-limiting param. Thanks for info.

Comment: One thing. The closing p tag should have slash escaped, ie: 
`$string = preg_replace('/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/is', '$1', $string, /* limit */ 1);`

Comment: @seanh: Or the pattern delimiter changed, as I have now done.

Answer (score 1):

```
function replaceFirst($input, $search, $replacement){
    $pos = stripos($input, $search);
    if($pos === false){
        return $input;
    }
    else{
        $result = substr_replace($input, $replacement, $pos, strlen($search));
        return $result;
    }
}

$string = "This is <p>Stackoverflow</p><p>site for programmers</p>";
echo $string;
echo replaceFirst($string, '<p>', '');
```

Output:

```
This is <p>Stackoverflow</p><p>site for programmers</p>
This is Stackoverflow</p><p>site for programmers</p>
```

Source: [#2031045](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3225633/2031045)

Hope this helps!

Comment: You could at least link to the original post, like I did?

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "This is <p>Stackoverflow</p><p>site for programmers</p>";

function remove_p($string)
{
    $string=str_replace('<p>','',$string,$temp=1);
    $string=str_replace('<\p>','',$string,$temp=1);
    return $string;
}

echo(remove_p($str));
```

The result is:
    This is Stackoverflow
    site for programmers

Answer (score 0):

Try using the method of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3225633/2031045).

```
function remove_p($string)
{
  return replaceFirst(replaceFirst($string, '<p>', ''), '</p>', '');
}
```

Or read about [Regular Expressions](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php).

Comment: It would have been more informative if you would have posted the custom function that you are calling in your answer.  Now readers will need to link chase to get the complete solution.